# Collapsing Folders in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, file-management

**In Windows 8, is there a quick way to "destroy" a folder, but copy it's contents into the folders directory?**

For example:

Folder F is located in Directory D. Folder F contains File 1 and File 2.

What I want to achieve is to quickly (Keyboard shortcut?) make it so that Folder F is deleted, but it's contents(File 1 & 2) are now in Directory D.

Maybe there is a shell extension?

Comment: Presumably in Windows 8 "folder" and "directory" are still one and the same?

Comment: With some sort of script it might be possible, but you're unlikely to find a ready-made shell extension for such an uncommon requirement. How often do you need o do this? What's the actual problem you're facing?